# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Depends'

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

I created a database using PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy and FastAPI. I set up JWT authentication for a route. But when I try it, I get the following error:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Depends'
    [SQL: SELECT "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".id AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_id", "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".user_id AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_user_id", "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".proficiency AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_proficiency", "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".title AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_title", "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".experience AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_experience", "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".last_used AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_last_used", "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".description AS "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill_description"
    FROM "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill"
    WHERE "tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-my_skill".user_id = %(user_id_1)s]
    [parameters: {'user_id_1': Depends(get_current_user)}]
    (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

I tried this:

```py
from src.app.common.models.models import My_Skill, Notification_My_Activity
from src.config.common.auth import oauth2
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, status, Response, HTTPException, File, UploadFile


def get_all_user_skill(db: Session, current_user: schemas.UserAuth = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    try:
        education_user_specific = db.query(My_Skill).filter(My_Skill.user_id == current_user).all()
        if education_user_specific:
            return education_user_specific
        if not education_user_specific:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                                detail=f"There is nothing to show")
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                            detail=properties.error_message)
```

Comment: Please set up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if you want others to be motivated to help you. There is too much going on here behind the scenes and your code is too specific. Often times, when you try to reduce and abstract your problem, you find the solution yourself. And if not, it is easier for others to help you. As of now, all I can tell you is that obviously the database API doesn't know what to do with the dependency object. Your `current_user` is **not** of type `schemas.UserAuth` inside your function.

Comment: `Depends` is a FastAPI construct and can only be used in FastAPI routes, i.e. functions marked with `@app.get`, `@app.post`, etc.